# Validation file extensions

Tags: laravel, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, serverless, laravel-vapor

I am working on a Laravel/VueJS Serverless project.

I am trying to whitelist/blacklist some file extensions for my AWS S3 bucket to avoid people uploading files I don't want.

I use Vapor in VueJS to temporary upload files and get a key that I send to my Controller in POST method to get back the file from temporary path and move it to the final path.

I have tried adding policies on my S3 bucket but I am still able to upload file extensions I should not.

If you have any clue, feel free to help me !

Thanks a lot !

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.